# Bubble sort in Mars Mips returns wrong results

Tags: mips, bubble-sort

I've been trying to sort an array by bubble sort in Mars Mips. The returned result is indeed in the correct order, but it missed some numbers
 `1, 2, 7, 7, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7`

Here is my work

```
.data
    arr: .word 1, 2, 7, 7, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7
    blank: .asciiz " "  # Newline string
.text

main:
    la $s0, arr          # Load the base address of the array
    li $t0, 0            # Initialize outer loop counter

for1: 
    beq $t0, 14, refresh
    
    
    addi $t1, $t0,1 #j = i+1
    sll $t3, $t0,2
    add $t3, $s0, $t3
    lw $t4, 0($t3) #a[i]
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    
    j for2
for2: 
    beq $t1, 15, for1
    sll $t2, $t1,2
    add $s1, $s0, $t2
    lw $s2, 0($s1)#a[j]
    blt $s2, $t4,swap
    
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    j for2
swap: 
        sw $s2, 0($t3)
        sw $t4, 0($s1)
        addi $t1, $t1,1
        j for2
refresh: 
    li $t0,0
    la $s0, arr 
print: 
    beq $t0, 15,exit
    
    
    li $v0,1
    lw $a0, 0($s0)
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, blank
    syscall
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    addi $s0, $s0, 4
    j print
exit: 
    li $v0, 10            # Exit program syscall
    syscall
```

The return result here is:
`1 2 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8`
instead of
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8`

Comment: In swap, after updating memory, recapture the newly discovered lowest in register, by copying s2 into t4.